# Counting circular arrangements with restrictions

Tags: combinatorics

Around a table are seated $m$ men and $f$ women. In how many ways can this be achieved if no two men sit together?

My son was given a variant of this (m=3 and f=8) on a test in highschool. The particular case is easy to count by hand but I could not find a general formula. Necklace counting results do not seem to apply directly, and I am trying to find a result without resorting to Pólya's enumeration theorem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are $(f-1)!$ ways in which women can seat around table. Now there are $f$ positions between women for men. So for first man there are $f$ positions to seat around. Now for second man there are $f-2$ positions to seat around. Simillarly for $m^{th}$ man there are remaining $f-m$ positions are available.

Hence by multiplication rule, total number of ways to sit around table are $(f-1)!*f*(f-1)*....*(f-m)$.

Comment: Thank you. I was trying to solve a different problem all the time... Can this reasoning be modified if we are not talking men and women but beads of two colors, resp. $m$ and $f$?

Comment: It depends on what you want to make using beads: necklaces or bracelets? Please visit following nice explanation https://www.jasondavies.com/necklaces/

Answer (score 0):

Make each man and his left-hand lady a unit, then it is a question of placing m units in f places.

Comment: It is not that simple if you don't consider the seats distinct, as is implied by a circular table.

Comment: Necklace counting results apply directly now, I think.